# Angular application requests freezing when console is open on network tab

Tags: angular, debugging

I'm having a problem with my angular application, whenever I open the Network tab and press f5, the requests freeze and i can't press F5 again, the browser gets really slow as time goes by, but it is possible to navigate normally inside the app, it's just the network tab that stops showing the requests like if something is pending

[network tab when the issue happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWRvn.png)

Does anyone have an idea of what may be happening? or maybe a suggestion on how I can debug this?

I recently upgraded this application from angular 13 to angular 15

Comment: Does it happen when you try production build?

Comment: it does, and it's even worse because the user can't login if we logout
i see no errors, just the login page loading nonstop

Comment: Looks like redirect loop, check router configuration.